# This object does not have an attribute named "this_rds_cluster_master_username"

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Trying to upgrade Aurora version to latest one. Before upgrading terraform plan is working fine. Once I did upgrading I'm getting:

Error: Unsupported attribute

on main.tf line 50, in locals:
50:

```
      "master_username" = module.db.this_rds_cluster_master_username
       module.db is a object, known only after apply
```

This object does not have an attribute named "this_rds_cluster_master_username".

I tried replacing module.db with variables var.this_rds_cluster_master_username and it worked, but I want to make changes in output file not with variables. Any assistance would really appreciated.

output.tf

```
            output "this_rds_cluster_master_username" {
                   value       = module.db.this_rds_cluster_master_username
                    description = "The master username."
                }
```

main.tf

```
         locals {
           rds_cluster_master_creds = {
          "master_username" = module.db.this_rds_cluster_master_username
          "master_password" = module.db.this_rds_cluster_master_password
                }
             }
```

How to modify output module?

#module db

```
module "db" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version = "5.2.0"
  engine            = "aurora-postgressql"
  engine_mode       = "serveless"
  engine_version    = null
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.rds_isolated.name
  vpc_id              = local.vpc_id
  deletion_protection = true
      }
```

#locals

```
 locals {
       rds_cluster_master_creds = {
      "master_username" = module.db.this_rds_cluster_master_username
      "master_password" = module.db.this_rds_cluster_master_password
            }
         }
```

Comment: Can you shown complete code demonstrating what is `module.db` and how do you use it?

Comment: module "db" {
                     source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
                    version = "5.2.0"
                   engine            = "aurora-postgressql"
                   engine_mode       = "serveless"
                  engine_version    = null
                 db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.rds_isolated.name
                vpc_id              = local.vpc_id
                deletion_protection = true

Comment: Can you please edit the question with correcly formated code blocks.

Comment: I've edited the question.I've aurora cluster db module and locals in main.tf. With old version of aurora it is working fine when I update with latest one 5.2.0 I'm getting issues.I dont know exact reason of issue but it may be related with output value. Do I need to update the output value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module [terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds#outputs) **does not have output** called `this_rds_cluster_master_username`. Instead it is called `db_master_password`. So instead of the following:

```
module.db.this_rds_cluster_master_username
```

you should be using

```
module.db.db_instance_username
```

Same for `this_rds_cluster_master_password`.